# Improvement on wicket HTML generator, is it possible to remove wicketpath?

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have a list with lots of elements (5000), the problem is that for 5000 elements wicket responds with 6MB and it takes 6 sec to generate this and another 5-6 sec is necessary for the browser to display those information.

An list element looks like this:

```
<li wicketpath="typeFacetPanel_modalwindow_content_filterTable_filterRow_2">
  <a href="?wicket:interface=:3:typeFacetPanel:modalwindow:content:filterTable:filterRow:2:filterLink::ILinkListener::" wicketpath="typeFacetPanel_modalwindow_content_filterTable_filterRow_2_filterLink">
    <span wicketpath="typeFacetPanel_modalwindow_content_filterTable_filterRow_2_filterLink_filterName">
      JPEG (1862)
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I'm looking to improve the response time (12s=6+6), if I replace the  tag with a simple text I get 1MB and the response time 4s(2.5+1.5), so I suppose I will get improvements if I manage to remove wicketpath attribute, or at least replace it with a shorter one.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is just a guess, but when your page takes a long time to render, it's often caused by an inefficient model, Like making a database call from `getObject()`.

Comment: Another guess is that your output might simply be too big for the second level page cache to handle in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: The output doesn't matter for serialization. It's the component tree that can be problematic. Ideally a profiler will tell if the issue is in rendering or serialization. AFAIK serialization happens when the output stream has already been closed, so that should not have an effect on getting the markup to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) you can turn wicket path off:

In your Web App class, do this:

```
@Override
protected void init(){
    super.init();
    getDebugSettings().setOutputComponentPath(false);
}
```

Actually, it's off by default, so you are apparently turning it on somewhere.

b) why on earth would you display 5000 items of anything? Have you ever heard of paging? How about using a  [`DataView`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/data/DataView.html) instead?

Comment: Sometimes paging is not an option. Like when you're displaying a tree.

Comment: @biziclop true but a) then you can use other specialized components that show just the branches you need b) I hope you don't plan on rendering a tree with 5000 nodes ...

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd Actually, I just have. :) But indeed I had to write a custom tree component that supported partial updates, it was completely unusable without it.

Comment: @biziclop you could try this tree, it supports node updates http://code.google.com/p/wicket-tree/

Comment: @tetsuo Thanks, I wanted to use it, but I'm stuck with Wicket 1.3 so I had no other option than to write my own. Anyway, displaying 5000 items on one page is a bad idea and you should avoid it if you can, but sometimes you can't. Extensive profiling and debugging is your only option then.

Comment: I use ListView to display data, and I use a JQuery script to search those rows, but now I'm thinking to replace this component with one that shows only most relevant X (20-100) rows or (when needed) to display all rows but in pages.

Answer (score 5):

Run your application in **DEPLOYMENT** mode, if not already doing so. There's a configuration item to remove the Wicket path from your markup such that it doesn't get generated. See the answer above to see how it is turned off. In normal mode this setting is not configured to do anything.

And for improvements in generation time we need to see some Java code before we can see why it takes 6 seconds to render.

Comment: Oh no, yet another superstar on this site. It's so awesome to have guys like you answering questions here!!! +1 for that (and of course for the answer)

Comment: @Sean, I've added him to [the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16137/are-there-famous-developers-using-stack-overflow/69631#69631).

Comment: @Lord Torgamus Cool, I always wondered if such a thing existed. Will check for missing candidates immediately :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a lazy load, for example: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Nonsense, this has nothing to do with the question. The question is about wicket, this is a jquery solution.

Comment: Yes, I know, its wicket that he can't do a lazy load.